# Sharing data across users in a Blazor Server App with Entity Framework?

Tags: entity-framework, blazor, blazor-server-side

I would like to create a Blazor Server App where a number of users would share read-write access to the same data, at the same time, using Entity Framework.

I've read about how best to use Entity Framework with Blazor, i.e. create new DBContexts for each request, for typical use-cases, i.e. users have separate data.

However, I would like a subset of my users (as defined by an attribute, e.g. department) to manipulate the same data, read and write, during concurrent sessions.

I am thinking of:

1. Fetching the data from the database the first time a user needs it, and keeping the data in memory (until some timeout perhaps).
2. All Blazor Server users that are meant to share the data (e.g department-related data) would just be accessing it from memory, reading, and writing in memory.
3. I am hoping each data attribute when editable in the UI would be updated automatically if is changed by a user, but could also save this manually (e.g. on leaving textbox).
4. When no users are accessing that data, or perhaps  after a timeout or regularly, the server app would write the data back to the database to persist it etc.

So in summary: fetch the data, let all related users access and edit that that data, write the data back to the database regularly, or when users edit individual attributes.

Would that work?

I realise some users may lose their changes (e.g. if they are entering a text box whilst another user is doing the same) but that should not be a big problem.

Is there an easy way to do this in Blazor with Entity Framework?

Thanks,
Morgan.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there an easy way to do this in Blazor with Entity Framework?

No.  What you propose is complex and difficult.

Instead use EF like it was designed to be used, and have the users manipulate the data in a shared database that supports concurrent access by multiple users.

Comment: Thank you, I am happy to do that, but I want each user to see the updates any other user makes automatically, i.e. without having to initiate a new fetch of the data from the database. Is this possible?  I was referring to this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/blazor-server-ef-core?view=aspnetcore-7.0

Comment: No.  Follow the guidance in that doc, and create a new DbContext for each operation.  When you fetch data from the DbContext you will see data altered by other users.

Comment: Right, but I want users who are editing the same data to continuously see updates to attributes (not necessary if the are editing the same textbox, for example), somewhat like a shared document in Google Docs or Office 365 (but for attributes, not a document). Thanks again.

Comment: Sounds like a case for SignalR hub. However, I would only use it for "Signals" to tell the clients to update the latest from the database as @DavidBrowne-Microsoft suggested.

Comment: There are also at least two NuGet packages with the text "EventAggregator" in the name. These use a pub/sub model for communicating changes made in one client to the other connected clients. I've found rolling a whole SignalR hub to be overkill for situations like this.

Comment: Thanks Brian and Lex, but I am planning to use Blazor Server, where all the business logic runs on the server, only the view updates are sent to the browser windows. I can't understand what's wrong with many users manipulating the same data in the server app's memory, i.e. one shared session?

Comment: It’s just not something that EF really helps with.

Comment: Yes, I agree. That's why I was separating out the sharing and updating (SignalR in Blazor Server) from fetch and update data (EF). Thanks for your comments, David.